# Что не так в коде? Помогите исправить пожалуйста

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал код (очень убогий). Скажите, пожалуйста, что надо исправить или исправленный вариант.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import cycle, compress

li = []
lii = []
done = []
url = input()
while url != 'конец':
    page = requests.get(url)
    page.encoding = 'utf-8'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    link = soup.find('table')
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        for td in tr.find_all('td'):
            li.append(td.text)
    li_new = list((compress(li, cycle([True, False, False, True, True]))))
    for i in range(len(li_new)):
        if li_new[i] == '5':
            lii.append(li_new[i-1])
    url = input()
for z in range(len(lii)):
    if lii.count(lii[z]) > 1:
        done.append(lii[z])
done = list(set(done))
print(*sorted(done), sep = '\n')
```

[image: Задание]

Нужно проанализировать эти 2 HTML кода

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Название фильма</th>
            <th>Режиссёр</th>
            <th>Актёрский состав</th>
            <th>Рейтинг фильма</th>
            <th>Год</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Седьмая печать</td>
            <td>Ингмар Бергман</td>
            <td>Макс фон Сюдов, Гуннар Бьёрнстранд, Биби Андерссон</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1957</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Остров проклятых</td>
            <td>Мартин Скорсезе</td>
            <td>Леонардо Ди Каприо, Марк Руффало, Бен Кингсли, Эмили Мортимер</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>2010</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Земляничная поляна</td>
            <td>Ингмар Бергман</td>
            <td>Виктор Шёстрём, Ингрид Тулин, Биби Андерссон</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1957</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Час волка</td>
            <td>Ингмар Бергман</td>
            <td>Макс фон Сюдов, Лив Ульман, Ингрид Тулин</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1968</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Второй код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Название фильма</th>
            <th>Режиссёр</th>
            <th>Актёрский состав</th>
            <th>Рейтинг фильма</th>
            <th>Год</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Земляничная поляна</td>
            <td>Ингмар Бергман</td>
            <td>Виктор Шёстрём, Ингрид Тулин, Биби Андерссон</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1957</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Фанни и Александр</td>
            <td>Ингмар Бергман</td>
            <td>Ева Фрёлинг, Бертил Гуве, Пернилла Альвин</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1982</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Седьмая печать</td>
            <td>Ингмар Бергман</td>
            <td>Макс фон Сюдов, Гуннар Бьёрнстранд, Биби Андерссон</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1957</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А почему вы решили, что в нём нужно что-то исправлять?

Comment: @andreymal не проходит какую-то проверку(какую-то, потому что она скрыта)